# How can I resample only a certain type of feature?

Tags: resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I want to resample from a  data set so that I only resample positive cases since my data is very unbalanced. Here is my code:

```
bootstrap=resample(Stroke['stroke']==1,replace=True,n_samples=800,random_state=1)
```

All I get back is a True\False array.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

Here is the code:

```
bootstrap=resample(Stroke[(Stroke['stroke'] == 1)],replace=True,n_samples=800,random_state=101)
```